NextJS generateStaticParams problems having 3 dynamic segments
I am using NextJS 14 and i have the following folder structure:
clients
|-page.tsx
|
|-[anagrafiche_id]
  |-layout.tsx
  |-page.tsx
  |-pageComponents.tsx
  |
  |-[doc_progetti_arch_id]
    |-layout.tsx
    |-page.tsx
    |-pageComponents.tsx
    |
    |-[doc_progetti_arch_dett_id]
      |-layout.tsx
      |-page.tsx
      |-pageComponents.tsx

inside each layout.tsx i have the function generateStaticParams like so:

clients/[anagrafiche_id]/[doc_progetti_arch_id]/layout.tsx

export async function generateStaticParams({ params: { anagrafiche_id } }: { params: { anagrafiche_id: string } }) {
    let progetti: Array<any> = await getDocProgettiArchId(anagrafiche_id);
    let toReturn = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < progetti.length; i++) {
        toReturn.push({
            doc_progetti_arch_id: progetti[i].doc_progetti_arch_id + "",
        });
    }

    return toReturn.map((el) => el);
}

The problem:
Everything works fine at build time, but when i navigate to /clients/103/285 when the page 285 is not "compiled", the function generateStaticProps reruns (which is what i want) but it recalculates even all the possibilities for the first segment, when it should keep the 103 page already "compiled" and use that id to grab just the associated ids.
I don't know if it is related, but i'm not even able to navigate to /clients/103/285 since the page stayes at /clients/103 even if the pathname has changed.
